# Correct use of "appointed"

Tags: grammar, usage

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> He was *appointed* as the President of the company.
>
> He was *appointed* President of the company.

Comment: The second sentence is the correct one. _Appointed_ is not usually followed by "as" .. A question of usage

Comment: Oh, I've seen the usage of "as" after "appointed in sentences.
For example,
http://gulfnews.com/business/emiratisation/uae-national-appointed-as-president-ceo-of-ge-gulf-1.1311361
http://news.yahoo.com/norways-stoltenberg-appointed-nato-chief-145433212.html
http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/mohan-verghese-chunkath-appointed-as-tamil-nadu-chief-secretary/article5844494.ece?textsize=small&test=2

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in the [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/appoint). Both uses are correct. The preposition *as* is optional, and very often omitted. Here's an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appointed+president%2C+appointed+as+president&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappointed%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappointed%20as%20president%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

["to appoint"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appoint) does not require (and, in fact, is usually not used with) the preposition "as". This means that *both* sentences are correct.

However, "He was appointed President of the company." is vastly [more commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appointed+president%2Cappointed+as+president&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappointed%20president%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappointed%20as%20president%3B%2Cc0). The same also applies for [chairmen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appointed+chairman%2Cappointed+as+chairman&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappointed%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappointed%20as%20chairman%3B%2Cc0) and [leaders](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appointed+leader%2Cappointed+as+leader&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappointed%20leader%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappointed%20as%20leader%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

This is good question (+1).

The article *the* is not usually used in the complement of a sentence when we want to say that someone **gained some position** even though it's the **only** position in the organization. Compare this -

> He was elected President in 1879 OVER I want to see **the** President.

Clearly, the second sentence is preferred.

> He was appointed President of the company.

Additional remark: In this case, *appointed* is used as a verb (it's an adjective as well) and thus it **does not take** *as*. Very good point by Josh51/ FEichinger

Comment: Oh, wow, I actually missed that, too, and only focused on the preposition. You're right, of course, the article is also usually omitted.

Comment: @FEichinger no worries. we miss at times. I missed (but now edited) the very imp *as* matter.